# Canny edge detector, but only for the object I want

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, image-recognition

[image: Example Image]

[image: Canny edge detection]

I want to detect only the tray edges in this picture. I tried with the Canny edge detector. It detects edges in the whole picture. What can I do to just detect the tray? I used the code [here](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/da/d22/tutorial_py_canny.html).

I just want it to detect the tray.

NEW UPDATE
Detected edges need to be recognized.

NEW NEW UPDATE
Template Matching

[Imlementing Template Matching](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J8Naz.png)

> https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d4/dc6/tutorial_py_template_matching.html
> (I used the code here)

[exampleImages](https://github.com/TryTestThinkWatchTheMovie/TrayImage/blob/main/README.md)

Comment: If either the table or the tray have a consistent, recognizable color, you should use that to detect the tray. Don’t do edge detection if you want to find the tray.

Comment: Tray colors are white or brown. So what should I do? I tried template matching and updated the question. Do you have any other suggestions ? @Cris Luengo